# How can I resolve this error, non matching values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out a way I can compare the data in three different columns in one sheet and pull any values that do not match into a new sheet.

Data Sheet: Validations
Target Sheet: Check Sheet

Example of Data in Sheet:

| Employee | Data 1 | Data 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 36.00 | 36.00 |
| 456 | 36.01 | 36.50 |
| 789 | 128 | 128 |

So when I run the code the only value I should see if my Check sheet would be the 2nd row as it's the only one that doesn't match. So should look like:

| Employee | Data 1 | Data 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | 36.01 | 36.50 |

When I run the code I've put together I can see that some matching has occurred as expected but also a lot of value that are the same have appeared as well. Code below! Any help would be really appreciated

```
Sub CheckForDuplicates_WH()
    ' define variables
    Dim validationsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim checkSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    
    ' set variables
    Set validationsSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Validations")
    Set checkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CheckSheet")
    lastRow = validationsSheet.Cells(validationsSheet.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row
    
    ' loop through each row in the Validations sheet
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        ' check if two of the cells in columns D, E, and F have different values
        If validationsSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value <> validationsSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value Then
            ' copy the values to the CheckSheet
            checkSheet.Cells(k + 3, "A").Value = validationsSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value
            checkSheet.Cells(k + 3, "B").Value = validationsSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value
            checkSheet.Cells(k + 3, "C").Value = validationsSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value
            k = k + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

When I run the code I've put together I can see that some matching has occurred as expected but also a lot of value that are the same have appeared as well. Code below! Any help would be really appreciated

[Some of the results I've had](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwA6T.png)

Comment: Maybe you need to `Application.Round` the data before comparing.

Comment: Can you include a few actual examples of records which were copied but should not have been?  Is it possible the records are not the same when the values are viewed in the formula bar, and it's just the default cell formatting which makes the values appear to be the same?

Comment: Sure: 77662 30.8000 30.8000
77768 30.8000 30.8000
80269 28.8000 28.8000
90810 0.5000 0.0000
91571 23.9667 23.9700
91596 30.8000 30.8000
91749 23.9667 23.9700
92364 0.5000 0.0000
93492 0.5000 0.0000
93499 7.1000 7.1000

Comment: 30.8000 is what you see in the cell, do you see something different in the formula bar however when you select that cell to see if the value is by chance 30.80001 vs 30.80002 ? If you only care about the 2 first decimals, rounding them down like BigBen says, should fix your issue.